HTML template navigation bar active/inactive buttons management without DRY
I'm implementing a Django forum app, it has a navigation bar. It is styled to display a chosen page of the site with "active" style (like, a brighter button), and others - as "inactive" (colored as usual).
As in normal template layout, I have a basic template, 'base.html', where the header with current time, authorization bar and navigation bar should be included, and {% block content %} left for other templates that inherit the basic template.
But I don't know how to implement the switching of "active/inactive" style of the navigation bar's buttons, so as for now I handle it with a separate navbar for every template, which violates DRY principle AS HELL:
base.html (pretty useless, as the same code is included in every other template of the site):
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body id="third">
    <header>
        {% include 'inc/_timedate.html' %}
        {% include 'inc/auth.html' %}
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a class="btn active" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
            <a class="btn" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
            <a class="btn" href="{% url 'characters' %}">Characters</a>
            <a class="btn" href="{% url 'episodes' %}">Episodes</a>
            <a class="btn" href="{% url 'forum:forum' %}">Forum</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

{% block pagination %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>

So, as you can see, the button displayed with the "active" style is the homepage button (style btn active). AFAIC, the navbar can be put into includes' folder and to be added to templates via {% include '' %}, as I did with "timedate.html" and "auth.html". But for that sake I need a solution (maybe, a script) that changes the style of navbar buttons depending on their chosen status by user.
I've googled for such scripts (I'm zero in JS, I can understand its logic and syntax, as it is pretty similar to C, but not to reproduce it), and found one that seems to do the trick (I put it right after <nav></nav> section, in the end of the <header> section):
        <script>
            var header = document.getElementByClassName("navbar");
            var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
            for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
                btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
                    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
                    this.className += " active";
                });
            }
        </script>

but it doesn't, unfortunately.
Can you give me an advice/hint/solution?
styles.css (if necessary):
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* Конец сброса CSS */

#current-date {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.navbar {
  width: 700px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 12px 15px 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1B182B;
}
.navbar .btn {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 12px 10px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(83, 50, 128, .84), rgba(71, 11, 150, .84) 80%);
}
.navbar .btn:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #1B182B;
}
.navbar .btn.active {
  background: #5214b8;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar .btn.inactive {
  background: #462f6b;
  color: grey;
  cursor: default;
}
<and others for other needs>


So firstly, getElementByClassName() is not a valid method. getElementsByClassName is valid, but returns a live HTMLCollection which much then be iterated over.

@mykaf, secondly, thirdly and so on then? :)

Aside from that, I would use classList.remove("active") to remove it from the element currently flagged as active, and then classList.add("active) to add it to the clicked item. classList (a TokenList), IMO, is easier to navigate than treating the className as a string to manipulate.

Your browser's console should be listing the errors with the invalid methods.

@mykaf, Maybe, you'll go for a full expanded answer?
The thing is I am a backender, so it's kind of a new world for me. I'll try what you have just offered. Hope that I can do it right.

If you are a backender, and since your "btn"s are all <a> tags, I would just look at the url to determine which one to set as active, and nix the JS altogether.

@mykaf, precisely the way I have already done. It's not elegant. It violates DRY. It's not how it supposed to be. And I'm maybe a backender, but I somehow managed to learn CSS and (partly) HTML.

If you insist on using javascript, it's still pointless to add the class to the anchor tag right before you navigate away. So you'd need to run it on page load


const header = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0];
const btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");

//use window.location.href, etc to get the current url instead of hardcoding
const currentURL = "mysite.com/episodes";
document.querySelector(`a.btn[href="${currentURL}"]`).classList.add("active");
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* Конец сброса CSS */

#current-date {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.navbar {
  width: 700px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 12px 15px 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1B182B;
}
.navbar .btn {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 12px 10px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(83, 50, 128, .84), rgba(71, 11, 150, .84) 80%);
}
.navbar .btn:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #1B182B;
}
.navbar .btn.active {
  background: #5214b8;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar .btn.inactive {
  background: #462f6b;
  color: grey;
  cursor: default;
}
  <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a class="btn" href="mysite.com/home">Home</a>
            <a class="btn" href="mysite.com/about">About</a>
            <a class="btn" href="mysite.com/characters">Characters</a>
            <a class="btn" href="mysite.com/episodes">Episodes</a>
            <a class="btn" href="mysite.com/forum">Forum</a>
        </nav>
    </header>




I guess, it's better to use window.location.pathname, as Django recommends to name the paths and use their names in templates.
Thank you, I'll try it.

Yehehehehehe, it works! :) Thank you very much, pinned answer as a solution! (with window.location.pathname though, as in my Django's urls.py my paths have name= attribute, which allows to call them by this name inside templates)

Since the nav items are <a> tags, and navigate away from the current screen anyway, I would probably solve this on the server side. I'm not familiar with django, but I think a hash table could work here.
# In your Django view or model
navigation_active_class = {}

# Adding key-value pairs
#initialize all to empty string
navigation_active_class['home'] = ''
navigation_active_class['about'] = ''
navigation_active_class['characters'] = ''
navigation_active_class['episodes'] = ''
navigation_active_class['forum'] = ''

#* psuedo-code; I don't know how to do this in django *
#get the url, maybe
full_url = request.build_absolute_uri()
#somehow match up the url with the home, about, etc keys.
# then set the appropriate navigation_active_class item to "active"
navigation_active_class[appropriate_key_from_prev_step] = 'active'

#display the nav
<nav class="navbar">
      <a class="btn {% navigation_active_class.get('home')%}" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
      <a class="btn {% navigation_active_class.get('about')%}" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
      <a class="btn {% navigation_active_class.get('characters')%}" href="{% url 'characters' %}">Characters</a>
      <a class="btn {% navigation_active_class.get('episodes')%}" href="{% url 'episodes' %}">Episodes</a>
      <a class="btn {% navigation_active_class.get('forum')%}" href="{% url 'forum:forum' %}">Forum</a>
</nav>


Okay, <a> navbar is not a required point, it's just how I've implemented it basing on my front-end knowledge and experience (relatively low). If there are any better ways to shape a navbar aside <a> tag (and which will not require such machinations in backend), I would be very glad to know

Well, <a> tags are the standard for navigation. They make the most sense. Otherwise you'd have to navigate via JS and event listeners anyway. The point is, you know which one should be flagged as active when the page is built on the server, so you might as well do it then. Flagging an element as active as you navigate away does no good. If you insist on doing this with Javascript, many use <ul> and <li>. Then you could use a similar approach to this answer with a Javascript Object, using window.location.href to find the url and match it to the correct object key.

can you describe the latter option in more detail? Because all that thing in the answer with navigation classes is new for me.
